# Python - MySQL multi-threaded writing

Tags: python, mysql, sql, multithreading

I am writing a simple scraper in python that will store scraped content in close to 20000 rows in MySQL database every time the program is run. I need to do this for 30 countries i.e. every time the program runs, it would have stored 600,000 rows of data in the database. I have 2 questions

1. Should I use one table and store all 30 countries' data or create 30 tables for faster queries.
2. Since my scraper is multithreaded - will be there issues if I am writing the data on every thread.

I am very new to programming. Any tips, suggestions or links to resources will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try and come back with your part of code that failed.

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.